# How to pull data from YouTube API to a Google Sheet with Channel Links

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm a complete newbie here. I tried many scripts to do the below. (Obviously from other questions here in stackoverflow - I'm not that proficient in writing codes yet)

My goal is to,

1. Read the channel ID from the channel links from the Sheet 1 A2:A
2. Pull Total Subscribers Count to B2:B
3. Pull Total Channel Views Count to C2:C
4. Pull Total Number of Video Uploads to D2:D

I have the API key already and tried almost everything that I can do with my knowledge to make this happen. But, I couldn't get it to work.

Can someone please educate me on how I can make this work?

I'd be so grateful for your help. Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Is that information available public using an apikey?  Please edit your question include [example] and describe **I couldn't get it to work.**  was there an error? did the data not come back?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Google Apps Script doing the described trick on a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qo_t31xAH6jE76QZy2ha1UUJgsJxLGtUzdpAUqqWnnw/edit?usp=sharing):

```js
// This Google Apps Script fills a Google Sheet with statistics associated to given YouTube channels.

// More precisely this script assumes that in columns A after the first row there are channel identifiers,
// which can be a channel ID (such as `UC0aMPje3ZACnQPKM_qzY0vw`) or any channel URL such as:
// - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCK_cUZLMpibyRiIdp0uF-lQ
// - https://www.youtube.com/user/Fairphone
// - https://www.youtube.com/c/lemondefr

function fills_statistics_associated_to_given_youtube_channels() {
  const A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const YOUTUBE_CHANNELS = YouTube.Channels;
  const CHANNEL_URL_PREFIX = "https://www.youtube.com/";
  // Consider an arbitrary number of channels written after the first row.
  for(var row = 2; row <= sheet.getLastRow(); row++)
  {
    const channelURL = sheet.getRange(row, A).getValue().toString().replace(CHANNEL_URL_PREFIX, "");
    // Retrieve the channel ID from the channel identifier provided.
    // If the channel URL provided is an username-based one, obtain the associated channel ID.
    var channelID;
    if(channelURL.startsWith("user/"))
      channelID = YOUTUBE_CHANNELS.list("id", {"forUsername": channelURL.replace("user/", "")}).items[0].id;
    // As YouTube Data API v3 Channels: list `forUsername` filter doesn't work for this kind of URL, proceed with a YouTube UI reverse-engineering approach.
    // This approach consists in obtaining JSON encoded JavaScript `ytInitialData` from the HTML code of the YouTube UI channel.
    else if(channelURL.startsWith("c/"))
    {
      // Note that the following reverse-engineering method isn't working currently because of escaped JSON syntax and I haven't found any clean way to parse it correctly.
      /*
      const channelHTML = UrlFetchApp.fetch(CHANNEL_URL_PREFIX + channelURL).getContentText();
      const ytInitialDataStr = channelHTML.split('">var ytInitialData = ', 2)[1].split(";</script>", 1)[0];
      const ytInitialDataJSON = JSON.parse(ytInitialDataStr);
      channelID = ytInitialDataJSON["responseContext"]["serviceTrackingParams"][0]["params"][6]["value"];
      continue;
      */

      // However by relying on a YouTube operational API instance doing this reverse-engineering method, it works fine. Nevertheless if YouTube servers detect the instance as suspicious, you have to host your own instance cf below. If you go this way, replace `yt.lemnoslife.com` to your instance hostname.
      // YouTube operational API source code is available at: https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API
      const channelStr = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?part=snippet&cId=" + channelURL.replace("c/", "")).getContentText();
      const channelJSON = JSON.parse(channelStr);
      channelID = channelJSON["items"][0]["id"];
    }
    // Not filtering with `if(channelURL.startsWith("channel/"))` in order to support channel ID too.
    else
      channelID = channelURL.replace("channel/", "");
    // For more details see YouTube Data API v3 Channels: list endpoint documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
    // Note that the channel ID retrieval can't be optimized in terms of HTTPS requests.
    // However could optimize the other HTTPS requests to YouTube Data API v3 by implementing using `id` filter to provide up to 50 channel IDs as documented by `maxResults`.
    const statistics = YOUTUBE_CHANNELS.list("statistics", {"id": channelID}).items[0].statistics;
    sheet.getRange(row, B).setValue(statistics.subscriberCount);
    sheet.getRange(row, C).setValue(statistics.viewCount);
    sheet.getRange(row, D).setValue(statistics.videoCount);
  }
}
```

Note that currently the case `channelURL.startsWith("c/")` relies on my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com).

Note that handles aren't supported by this code, even if [it's possible to support them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74324720).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. As I see that the code can't work on links that has "c", is there a way by any chance that we can make it work by feeding only the channel ID like this (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bbQuBYfwZJDobvnwAb5sgOSuFXBiuekvpvVTEaR-NYY/edit?usp=sharing)?

Comment: @Bookus In your Google Sheet both `Fairphone` and `lemondefr` wouldn't work as there is an ambiguity about whether they are `c/` or `user/` URLs (as it matters for `forUsername`). However just providing the channel ID (such as `UCK_cUZLMpibyRiIdp0uF-lQ`) or the channel ID based URL (such as https://youtube.com/channel/UCK_cUZLMpibyRiIdp0uF-lQ) would work.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying... If that 's the case, I'm wondering how can I pull the data for channel URLs that have "c/" in them. Please advice if you have any workarounds for that. TIA <3

Comment: [I updated my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73807243/revisions). Note that currently YouTube servers detect the official YouTube operational API instance (https://yt.lemnoslife.com) [as suspicious](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/11), so you have to [host your own instance](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API#install-your-own-instance-of-the-api) to make the updated script work.

Comment: I added another clearer exhaustive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function myFunction() {

  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  let range = sheet.getRange(2,1, sheet.getLastRow()-1);
  let values = range.getValues();
  let mapValues = values.map(function(sr){return sr[0];}).join(",");
  let results = YouTube.Channels.list("statistics, contentDetails",{id: mapValues});
  let modifyResults = results.items.map(function(sr){return [sr.statistics.subscriberCount, sr.statistics.videoCount, sr.statistics.viewCount]});

  sheet.getRange(2,2, modifyResults.length,modifyResults[0].length).setValues(modifyResults);
    
}
```