# YouTube Data API Get Channel by Handle

Tags: youtube-data-api

[Introducing handles: A new way to identify your YouTube channel](https://blog.youtube/news-and-events/introducing-handles-a-new-way-to-identify-your-youtube-channel/)

Does the YouTube Data API support querying for a channel by it's @handle?  This does not seem to be supported.

ex: https://www.youtube.com/@lionsgatemovies

`forUsername` param

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id,snippet&forUsername=@lionsgatemovies

{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "RuuXzTIr0OoDqI4S0RU6n4FqKEM",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  }
}
```

`id` param

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id,snippet&id=@lionsgatemovies

{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "RuuXzTIr0OoDqI4S0RU6n4FqKEM",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  }
}
```

None of the supported filter params seem to be appropriate:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "No filter selected. Expected one of: mySubscribers, forUsername, mine, managedByMe, categoryId, id",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "No filter selected. Expected one of: mySubscribers, forUsername, mine, managedByMe, categoryId, id",
        "domain": "youtube.parameter",
        "reason": "missingRequiredParameter",
        "location": "parameters.",
        "locationType": "other"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems duplicated with [this answered StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74323173).

Comment: Note that, while you can't fetch a channel given a handle, the handle itself is stored inside the [channel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) response (`channel -> snippet -> customUrl`).

Answer (score 6):

You can use Search API with `q` parameter set to `@handle`

```
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=%40kevinrooke&type=channel&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]'

{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "AYlro9VG2vMtdew4OQiWoQM8Rs0",
  "regionCode": "LT",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "ls9E_ctoa-RLsqznJwxWlHHIE1s",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UCTdxV_ItCZMayyzGkw7P_qQ"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2017-05-27T03:56:38Z",
        "channelId": "UCTdxV_ItCZMayyzGkw7P_qQ",
        "title": "Kevin Rooke",
        "description": "Interviews with the builders bringing the Lightning Network to life. ⚡kerooke@fountain.fm.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AMLnZu-SpmaNjx7KOMqs5Cr7ZthU60BaQApzt89_dHOlcg=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AMLnZu-SpmaNjx7KOMqs5Cr7ZthU60BaQApzt89_dHOlcg=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AMLnZu-SpmaNjx7KOMqs5Cr7ZthU60BaQApzt89_dHOlcg=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Kevin Rooke",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2017-05-27T03:56:38Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Confirmed. this is the right answer. 

Comment: Nah, if the handle you want was not unique enough, you would get the most popular channel with the keyword instead. For example, https://www.youtube.com/@illustrator will give you Adobe Illustrator channel.

Comment: or a list of completely unrelated channels in the case of @MauLerYT, among which is *not* included the URL of the channel itself. it works if you search for the full URL tho (https://www.youtube.com/@MauLerYT). Would have preferred to use the API, but I guess now they're just gonna have to deal with scraping because a 100 channel *search* will suck up your entire daily quota anyway so it's not like it would be useful if it even worked. This could have been a 1 quota point operation (or less).

Comment: funnier yet is the support page just says "oh the devs monitor stackoverflow". they deserve every bit of scraping they get

Answer (score 1):

As of this moment (17th Nov 2022), YouTube [has yet to update the Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history) with @handle support.

Answer (score 1):

The `channelId` was scattered around in the Html. You can easily parse them after fetching the url with the handle.

```js
const html = await(await fetch(url)).text()
const channelId = html.match(/(?<=channelId(":"|"\scontent="))[^"]+/g)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The official API doesn't support this and using the
search API can return the most popular channel instead of the exact name match.

**The best solution I have found after reading through all the stackoverflow posts and different Youtube APIs is to use [Youtube.js](https://github.com/LuanRT/YouTube.js) to interface with InnerTube(Youtube's internal API) and resolve the channel url.**

If you have the full channel url, there's a resolve url endpoint that will return an object with the id.

```js
//innerTubeUtils.ts

import { Innertube } from "youtubei.js";

export async function getChannelFromUrl(url: string) {
  const innerTube = await Innertube.create(/* options */);
  const resolved = await innerTube.resolveURL(url);
  const channelId = resolved.payload.browseId;
  return channelId;
}
```

The payload you get back will a browseId property, which is the channelId.

*[Courtesy of ChunkyProgrammer for providing this solution!](https://github.com/LuanRT/YouTube.js/issues/413#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20the%20full%20channel%20url%2C%20there%27s%20a%20resolve%20url%20endpoint%20that%20will%20return%20an%20object%20with%20the%20id.)*

Answer (score 1):

now you can use the [new parameter](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/commit/dc515e21ebc0d64e9fdd6a6aa16aeeede8e2929b) `forHandle` ([docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#parameters))

> The forHandle parameter specifies a YouTube handle, thereby requesting the channel associated with that handle. The parameter value can be prepended with an @ symbol. For example, to retrieve the resource for the "Google for Developers" channel, set the forHandle parameter value to either GoogleDevelopers or @GoogleDevelopers.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the python snippet while we are waiting for YouTube API's official support. This is inspired by [goodhyun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/777745/goodhyun)'s wonderful thoughts.

```py
import requests
import re

# return YouTube channel id via handle or False if failed
def scraping_get_channel_id_from_handle(handle:str):
    if handle.find('@') == -1:
        handle = '@' + handle

    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/' + handle
    resp = requests.get(url)

    if resp.status_code == 200:
        found = re.findall('<meta itemprop="channelId" content="([^"]*)"', resp.text)

        return found[0]
    else:
        return False
```