# Why searching a channel by its handle doesn't work, however it's reachable by its id?

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-channels

A bunch of SO answers shows that the YouTube API v3 doesn't yet provide a trivial way to get a YouTube channel by its **handle**. A workaround is to perform a search with the handle as a search term :

- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37947865) of *How to get Youtube channel details using Youtube data API if channel has custom url*
- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74902789) of *YouTube Data API Get Channel by Handle*
- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74323173/how-to-map-youtube-handles-to-channel-ids/74324720#74324720) of *How to map youtube handles to channel IDs*
- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75374713) of *How can I get YouTube channel ID using channel name URL?*

Then, to retrieve only the first result being a channel, this piece of code can be used:

```
SearchResource.ListRequest SRLR = this.YouTubeService.Search.List("snippet");
SRLR.Q = Handle;
// SRLR.SafeSearch = SearchResource.ListRequest.SafeSearchEnum.None;
SRLR.MaxResults = 1;
// SR contains the first result that *should* be the searched channel
// otherwise an exception is thrown 
SearchResult SR =
    SRLR.Execute().Items.Where(x => x.Id.Kind == "youtube#channel").Single();
```

Then, this result can be checked by retrieving the channel by its Id and comparing the search term with the actual channel handle.

```
ChannelsResource.ListRequest CRLR = this.YouTubeService.Channels.List(part);
CRLR.Id = SR.Snippet.ChannelId;
Channel Channel = CRLR.Execute().Items.Single();

if (Channel.Snippet.CustomUrl != Handle)
    throw new System.Exception($"No channel with handle \"{Handle}\"");
```

Finally, it is possible to process the channel itself.

This works very well with some handles like `@aha` or `@Queen`.

But the search doesn't return a channel for the handle `@lachaiseproductions1654`. Instead, a list of 5 unrelated videos is returned.

However, The channel appears in a YouTube search.

What's more, a test suggested by Benjamin Loison in the comments shows that the HTTP call itself works, both from a web browser and with the `cURL` utility.

```bash
$ curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=@lachaiseproductions1654&type=channel&key=API_KEY'
```

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "e7MNUTzPTPLLstR3AudmySikeJI",
  "regionCode": "FR",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "ELI76vrmCruoLt7k4Bb3ffs4V8s",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UCDSqPuB6YKO4E5FjKP1R23Q"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the code, using YouTube Api, I tried to disable `SafeSearch` (commented out above) just in case although there should be no reason, but it had no effect.

Yet this channel can be reached by its id (`UCDSqPuB6YKO4E5FjKP1R23Q`). Why did I miss?

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=@lachaiseproductions1654&type=channel&key=API_KEY returns correctly as the first result the channel you are looking for, right?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison, I should have started with that. I'm using right now another device, so I can't confirm yet it will work in the dev environment. I'll give an update asap. Thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison, I guess I shound use a sniffer like tcpdump or Wireshark to understand what's going on using the .NET YouTube Api.

Comment: I'm not keen on .NET YouTube API library, maybe just working with its source code if you have access to it would be simpler.