# YouTube API throws "error:400, no filter selected"-previous solutions not working

Tags: api, request, youtube

The headline says it all. As far as I can see I provided a filter id. So not sure why it is throwing this error. Here are my codes-

```py
import requests
import json

class YTstats:

    def __init__(self, api_key, channel_id):
        self.api_key=api_key
        self.channel_id=channel_id
        self.channel_statistics=None

    def get_channel_statistics(self):
        url=f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id{self.channel_id}&key={self.api_key}'
        #print(url)
        json_url=requests.get(url)
        data=json.loads(json_url.text)
        print(data)
```

Main.py-

```py
from youtube_statistics import YTstats

API_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
channel_id="@petebellis"

yt=YTstats(API_KEY, channel_id)

yt.get_channel_statistics()
```

Here is the error-

```py
{'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'No filter selected. Expected one of: mySubscribers, managedByMe, id, forUsername, categoryId, mine', 'errors': [{'message': 'No filter selected. Expected one of: mySubscribers, managedByMe, id, forUsername, categoryId, mine', 'domain': 'youtube.parameter', 'reason': 'missingRequiredParameter', 'location': 'parameters.', 'locationType': 'other'}]}}
```

I removed the api key but used an actual working api key. Here it is just replaced with `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...`. Any help to point out what am I doing wrong will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You forgot an `=` in `url` to correctly pass `id`. So replace:

```py
url=f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id{self.channel_id}&key={self.api_key}'
```

with:

```py
url=f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={self.channel_id}&key={self.api_key}'
```

2. YouTube Data API v3 doesn't support channel handles, so you have to first [resolve the channel id from the channel handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74324720)