# Getting Video Links from Youtube Channel in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, youtube

I am using Selenium in Python to scrape the videos from Youtube channels' websites. Below is a set of code. The line `videos = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer')` repeatedly returns no links to the videos (a.k.a. the `print(videos)` after it outputs an empty list). How would you modify it to find all the videos on the loaded page?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/wendoverproductions/videos')

videos = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer')
print(videos)

urls = []
titles = []
dates = []

for video in videos:
    video_url = video.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='.//*[@id="video-title"]').get_attribute('href')
    urls.append(video_url)
    video_title = video.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='.//*[@id="video-title"]').text
    titles.append(video_title)
    video_date = video.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='.//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[2]').text
    dates.append(video_date)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### ***Implementation using Selenium:***

First of all, I wanna solve the problem meaning wanted to pull data with the help of `YouTube API` and I'm about to reach the goal but for some API's restrictions like API KEY's rquests restrict and  some other complexities, I couldn't grab complete data that's why I go with super powerful Selenium engine as my last resort and it works like a charm.

**Full working code as an example:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#All are optional
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--disable-Advertisement")
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

s=Service('./chromedriver')
driver= webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=options)

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/wendoverproductions/videos')
time.sleep(3)

item = []
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")

item_count = 180

while item_count > len(item):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")

    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
    

data = []
try:
    for e in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#details'))):
        title = e.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a#video-title-link').get_attribute('title')
        vurl = e.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a#video-title-link').get_attribute('href')
        views= e.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//*[@id="metadata"]//span[@class="inline-metadata-item style-scope ytd-video-meta-block"][1]').text
        date_time = e.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//*[@id="metadata"]//span[@class="inline-metadata-item style-scope ytd-video-meta-block"][2]').text
        data.append({
            'video_url':vurl,
            'title':title,
            'date_time':date_time,
            'views':views
            })
except:
    pass
    
item = data
print(item)
print(len(item))
# df = pd.DataFrame(item)
# print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[{'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oL0umpPPe-8', 'title': 'Samsung’s Dangerous Dominance over South Korea', 'date_time': '10 days ago', 'views': '2.3M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBp_NgrrtPM', 'title': 'China’s Electricity Problem', 'date_time': '3 weeks ago', 'views': '1.9M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBNcYxHJPLE', 'title': 'How the World’s Wealthiest People Travel', 'date_time': '1 month ago', 'views': '2.3M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIpPuJ_r8Xg', 'title': 'The US Military’s Massive Global Transportation System', 'date_time': '1 month ago', 'views': '1.6M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MY8AB1wYOtg', 'title': 'The Absurd Logistics of Concert Tours', 'date_time': '2 months ago', 'views': '1.4M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xzINLykprA', 'title': 'Money’s Mostly Digital, So Why Is Moving It So Hard?', 'date_time': '2 months ago', 'views': '1.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f66GfsKPTUg', 'title': 'How This Central African City Became the World’s Most Expensive', 'date_time': '3 months ago', 'views': '3.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDLkOWW0_xg', 'title': 'The Simple Genius of NYC’s Water Supply System', 'date_time': '3 months ago', 'views': '1.8M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9jirFqex6g', 'title': 'Europe’s Experiment: Treating Trains Like Planes', 'date_time': '3 months ago', 'views': '2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoWcQUjNM8o', 'title': 'How the YouTube Creator Economy Works', 'date_time': '4 months ago', 'views': '1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0Xx0E8cs7U', 'title': 'The Incredible Logistics Behind Weather Forecasting', 'date_time': '4 months ago', 'views': '1.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0aGGOK4kAM', 'title': 'Australia Had a Mass-Shooting Problem. Here’s How it Stopped', 'date_time': '5 months ago', 'views': '947K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AW3gaelBypY', 'title': 'The Carbon Offset Problem', 'date_time': '5 months ago', 'views': '1.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhYl7Jjefo8', 'title': 'Jet Lag: The Game - A New Channel by Wendover Productions', 'date_time': '6 months ago', 'views': '328K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oESoI6XxZTg', 'title': 'How to Design a Theme Park (To Take Tons of Your Money)', 'date_time': '6 months ago', 'views': '1.9M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQbmpecxS2w', 'title': 'Why Gas Got So Expensive (It’s Not the War)', 'date_time': '6 months ago', 'views': '3.4M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_7CGl6VWaQ', 'title': 'How Cyberwarfare Actually Works', 'date_time': '7 months ago', 'views': '1.9M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9pxFgJwxFE', 'title': 'The Incredible Logistics Behind Corn Farming', 'date_time': '7 months ago', 'views': '1.6M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrTrpwzVt4g', 'title': 'The Sanction-Fueled Destruction of 
the Russian Aviation Industry', 'date_time': '8 months ago', 'views': '4.3M 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1JlYZQG3lI', 'title': "Why There are Now So Many Shortages (It's Not COVID)", 'date_time': '1 year ago', 'views': '7.7M 
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4dOCfWlgBw', 'title': 'The Insane Logistics of Shutting Down the Cruise Industry', 'date_time': '1 year ago', 'views': '2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CuPqeIJr3U', 'title': "China's Vaccine Diplomacy", 'date_time': '1 year ago', 'views': '916K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlTq8DbRs4k', 'title': "The UK's Failed Experiment in Rail Privatization", 'date_time': '1 year ago', 'views': '1.5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjiH3mpxyrQ', 'title': 'How to Start an Airline', 'date_time': '1 year ago', 'views': '1.8M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLcqJ2DclEg', 'title': 'The Electric Vehicle Charging Problem', 'date_time': '1 year ago', 'views': '4.4M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gdCH1XUIlE', 'title': "How Air Ambulances (Don't) Work", 'date_time': '1 year ago', 'views': '1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qanMpnYsjk', 'title': "How Amazon's Super-Complex Shipping System 
Works", 'date_time': '1 year ago', 'views': '2.9M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7R7jNWHp0D0', 'title': 'The News You Missed in 2020, From Every Country in the World (Part 2)', 'date_time': '1 year ago', 'views': '1.3M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIFV_Z7Y9_w', 'title': 'The News You Missed in 2020, From Every Country in the World (Part 1)', 'date_time': '1 year ago', 'views': '2.3M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXRtNwUju5g', 'title': "How China Broke the World's Recycling", 'date_time': '1 year ago', 'views': '3.9M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTyUE162lrw', 'title': 
'Why Long-Haul Low-Cost Airlines Always Go Bankrupt', 'date_time': '1 year ago', 'views': '1.3M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAEydOjNWyQ', 'title': 'How Living at the 
South Pole Works', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '2.3M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BCY0SPOFpE', 'title': "Egypt's Dam Problem: The Geopolitics of the Nile", 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '1.8M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_rXhuaI0W8', 'title': 'The 8 Flights That Show How COVID-19 Reinvented Aviation', 'date_time': 
'2 years ago', 'views': '1.3M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ongqf93rAcM', 'title': "How to Beat the Casino, and How They'll Stop You", 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '3.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byW1GExQB84', 'title': 'Distributing the COVID Vaccine: The Greatest Logistics Challenge Ever', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '911K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTIDCA7mjZs', 'title': 'How to Illegally Cross the Mexico-US Border', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '1.7M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_akzwzghWQ', 'title': 'How COVID-19 Broke the Airline 
Pricing Model', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '2.3M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7C1fPocIFgU', 'title': 'The Broken Economics of Organ Transplants', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '600K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3J06af5xHD0', 'title': 'The Final Years of Majuro [Documentary]', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgiMqePRp0Y', 'title': 'The Logistics of Covid-19 Testing', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '533K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rtmhv5qEBg0', 'title': "Airlines' Protocol for After a Plane Crash", 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '1.5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GMoUmvw8kU', 'title': 'Why Taiwan and China are Battling over Tiny Island Countries', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '855K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlPrAKtegFQ', 'title': 'How Long-Haul Trucking Works', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '2.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAG4zCsiA_w', 'title': 'Why Helicopter Airlines Failed', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '1.5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtX-Ibi21tU', 'title': 'The Five Rules of Risk', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '1M 
views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2oPk20OHBE', 'title': "Air Cargo's Coronavirus Problem", 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '1.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABIkWS_YavM', 'title': 'How Offshore Oil Rigs Work', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '2.4M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pNBAxx4IRo', 'title': 
"How the US' Hospital Ships Work", 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '1.5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VX2e2iEg_pM', 'title': 'COVID-19: How Aviation is Fighting for Survival', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '1.3M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ppjv0H-Yt5Q', 'title': 'The Logistics of the US Census', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '887K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvUpSFGRqEo', 'title': 'How Boeing Will Get the 737 MAX Flying Again', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '1.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Sh7hghljuQ', 'title': 'How China Built a Hospital in 10 Days', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '2.8M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpcUVOjUrKk', 'title': 'The Business of Ski Resorts', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '2.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCEwPio2bkg', 'title': "American Sports' Battle for China", 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '494K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-QejUTDCWw', 'title': "The World's Most Useful Airport 
[Documentary]", 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '9M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RyG7nzteG64', 'title': 'The Logistics of the US Election', 'date_time': '2 years 
ago', 'views': '838K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSw7fWCrDk0', 'title': 'Amtrak’s Grand Plan for Profitability', 'date_time': '2 years ago', 'views': '1.5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SDUm1bx7Zc', 'title': "Australia's China Problem", 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '6.8M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1a73gdNs0M', 'title': 'The US Government Program That Pays For Your Flights', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '886K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLS9IK693KI', 'title': 'The Logistics of Disaster Response', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '938K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnfoTAxhpzQ', 'title': 'Why So Many Airlines are Going Bankrupt', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '2.9M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erS2YMYcZO8', 'title': 'The Logistics of Filming Avengers', 'date_time': '3 
years ago', 'views': '1.5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjbYloKJX7c', 
'title': "Boeing's China Problem", 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '3.4M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0qt0hdCQtg', 'title': "The US' Overseas Military Base Strategy", 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '3.6M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9ttpHvK6yw', 'title': 'How to Stop an Epidemic', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '2.3M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJ_LUFBSoqM', 'title': "The NFL's Logistics Problem", 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '2.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYPrH4xANpU', 'title': 'The Economics of Private Jets', 'date_time': '3 years 
ago', 'views': '4.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgsxapE27NU', 'title': "The World's Shortcut: How the Panama Canal Works", 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '4.4M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1f2GwWLB3k', 'title': 'How Air Traffic 
Control Works', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '4M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2-ehDQM6TM', 'title': 'Extremities: A New Scripted Podcast from Wendover', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '193K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17oZPYcpPnQ', 'title': "Iceland's Tourism Revolution", 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '1.3M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUsqnD9-42g', 'title': 'Mini Countries Abroad: How Embassies Work', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '5.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfNEOfEGe3I', 'title': 'The Economics That Made Boeing Build the 737 Max', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '2.4M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkRRo5DN9lI', 'title': 'The Logistics of the International Space Station', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '3.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3jfvncofiA', 'title': 'How Airlines Decide Where to Fly', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '2.5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xX0ozxrZlEQ', 'title': 'How Rwanda is Becoming the Singapore of Africa', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '6.4M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9poImReDFeY', 'title': 'How Freight Trains Connect the World', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '2.3M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69EVxLLhciQ', 'title': 'How Hong Kong Changed Countries', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '2.5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdy0gBVWAzE', 'title': 'Living Underwater: 
How Submarines Work', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '10M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnoUBfLxZz0', 'title': 'The Super-Fast Logistics of Delivering Blood By Drone', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msjuRoZ0Vu8', 'title': 'The New Economy of the Warming Arctic', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '844K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0pS3Zx7Fc8', 'title': 'Cities at Sea: How Aircraft Carriers Work', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '13M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNUomfuWuA8', 'title': 'The Rise of 20-Hour Long Flights', 'date_time': '3 years ago', 'views': '3.7M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JDoll8OEFE', 'title': 'Why China Is so Good at Building Railways', 'date_time': '4 years ago', 'views': '8.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cjIWMUgPtY', 'title': 'The Magic Economics of Gambling', 'date_time': '4 years ago', 'views': '2.5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cognzTud3Wg', 'title': 'Why the World is Running Out of 
Pilots', 'date_time': '4 years ago', 'views': '4.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EodxubsO8EI', 'title': 'How Fighting Wildfires Works', 'date_time': '4 years ago', 'views': '1.6M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30XpSozOZII', 'title': 'How to Build a $100 Million Satellite', 'date_time': '4 years ago', 'views': '1.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQV_DKQkT8o', 'title': "How Africa is Becoming China's China", 'date_time': '4 years ago', 'views': '8.7M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdU1WTBJMl0', 'title': 'How Airports Make Money', 'date_time': '4 years ago', 'views': '4.5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OLVFa8YRfM', 'title': 'The Insane Logistics of Formula 1', 'date_time': '4 years ago', 'views': '6.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdNDYBt9e_U', 'title': 'The Most Valuable Airspace in the World', 'date_time': '4 years ago', 'views': '5.6M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5r90DYjZ76g', 'title': "Guam: Why America's Most Isolated Territory Exists", 'date_time': '4 years ago', 'views': '6M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Y1kJpHBn50', 'title': 'How to Design Impenetrable Airport Security', 'date_time': '4 years ago', 'views': '4.8M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiRBQxHrxNw', 'title': 'Space: The Next Trillion Dollar Industry', 'date_time': '4 years ago', 'views': '3.4M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-s3j-ptJD10', 'title': 'The Logistics of Living in Antarctica', 'date_time': '4 
years ago', 'views': '5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3qfeoqErtY', 'title': 'How Overnight Shipping Works', 'date_time': '4 years ago', 'views': '7.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IvAvHjYoLUU', 'title': 'Why Cities Exist', 'date_time': 
'4 years ago', 'views': '3.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72hlr-E7KA0', 'title': 'How Airlines Price Flights', 'date_time': '4 years ago', 'views': '3.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voozHXadYYE', 'title': 'The Gene Patent Question', 'date_time': '4 years ago', 'views': '587K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uU3kLBo_ruo', 'title': 'The Nuclear Waste Problem', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '3.7M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1YMPk3XhCc', 'title': 'The Little Plane War', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '4.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h97fXhDN5qE', 'title': "Elon Musk's Basic Economics", 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': 
'5.9M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiBF6v5UAAE', 'title': "China's Geography Problem", 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '12M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-cjfTG8DbwA', 'title': 'Why Public Transportation Sucks in the US', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '3.3M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ql0Op1VcELw', 'title': "What's Actually the Plane of the Future", 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaGG50laHgI', 'title': 'TWL is back! (But not here...)', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '303K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yT9bit2-1pg', 'title': 'How to Stop a Riot', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '5.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-WO-c9xHms', 'title': 'How Geography Gave the US Power', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '3.5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Jfrzkmzyc', 'title': 'Why Chinese Manufacturing Wins', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '6.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGXahSnA_oA', 'title': 'How Airlines Schedule Flights', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '4M views'}, 
{'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4PW66_g6XA', 'title': 'How to Fix Traffic Forever', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '3.9M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j48Z3W35FI0', 'title': 'How the US Government Will Survive Doomsday', 'date_time': '5 years 
ago', 'views': '4.7M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MP1OAm7Pzps', 'title': 'Why the Northernmost Town in America Exists', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '8.9M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkCeKc1GTMs', 'title': 'Which Country Are International Airports In?', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '3.7M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nu2WOxXxsHw', 'title': 'How the Post Office Made America', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '1.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSxSgbNQi-g', 'title': 'Small Planes Over Big Oceans (ETOPS Explained)', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '3.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcDwtO4RWmo', 'title': "Canada's New Shipping Shortcut", 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '3.7M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqWksuyry5w', 'title': 'Why Airlines Sell More Seats Than They Have', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '2.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwjwePe-HmA', 'title': 'Why Trains are so Expensive', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '3.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3C_5bsdQWg', 'title': "Russia's Geography Problem", 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '8.6M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzB5xtGGsTc', 'title': 'The Economics of Airline Class', 'date_time': '5 years 
ago', 'views': '10M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1QEj09Pe6k', 'title': "Why Planes Don't Fly Faster", 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '7.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJRqB1xtIxg', 'title': "The US President's $2,614 Per Minute Transport System", 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '11M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ancuYECRGN8', 'title': 'Every State in the US', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '6.5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bL2WPDtLYNU', 'title': 'How 
to Make First Contact', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '3.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PWWtqfwacQ', 'title': 'Why Cities Are Where They Are', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '5.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lj127TKu4Q', 'title': 'Is the European Union a Country?', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1CVVoAihBc', 'title': 'Every Country in the World 
(Part 2)', 'date_time': '5 years ago', 'views': '3.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-b4SUOfn_4', 'title': 'Every Country in the World (Part 1)', 'date_time': '5 years 
ago', 'views': '8.6M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thqbjA2DC-E', 'title': 'The Five Freedoms of Aviation', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '3.4M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rk2hPrEnk8', 'title': "Why Chicken Sandwiches Don't Cost $1500", 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '3M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQSxPzafO_k', 'title': 'Urban Geography: Why We Live Where We Do', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '3.3M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlIdzF1_b5M', 'title': 'Big Plane vs Little Plane (The Economics of Long-Haul Flights)', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '4.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpfvOc8HJdg', 'title': 'TWL #10.5: Argleton (+ Patreon)', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '202K views'}, {'video_url': 
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ouiTMXuDAQ', 'title': 'How Much Would it Cost to Live on the Moon?', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-aQ2E0mlRQI', 'title': 'The Plane Highway in the Sky', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '4.4M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbEfzuCLoAQ', 'title': 'Why Trains Suck in America', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '5.8M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7CvEt51fz4', 'title': 'How Maritime Law Works', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '3.5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PsmkAxVHdM', 'title': 'Why College is so Expensive', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '1.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JoYNhX15w4k', 'title': 'TWL #10: The Day Sweden Switched Driving Directions', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '1.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1c-jBfZPVv4', 'title': 'TWL #9: The Secret Anti-Counterfeit Symbol', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '1.4M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=069y1MpOkQY', 'title': 'How Budget Airlines Work', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '9.2M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7RHv_MIIT0', 'title': 'TWL #8: Immortality Through Quantum Suicide', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '1.8M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Oe8T3AvydU', 'title': 'Why Flying is So Expensive', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 
'views': '4.8M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnEyjwdoj7g', 'title': 'TWL #7: This Number is Illegal', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '3.7M views'}, {'video_url': 
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XdYbmova_s', 'title': 'TWL #6: Big Mac Economics', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '1.6M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F53TA37Mqck', 'title': 'TWL #5: Timekeeping on Mars', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '810K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6o5C-i02c8', 'title': 'TWL #4: Which Way Should Toilet Paper Face?', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '739K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JllpzZgAAl8', 'title': 'TWL #3: Paper Towns- Fake Places Made to Catch Copyright Thieves', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '1.1M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_iaurPRhCs', 'title': 'TWL #2: Bir Tawil- The Land Without a Country', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '852K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ugvJi2pIck', 'title': 'TWL #1: Presidents Are 4x More Likely to be Lefties', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '546K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRWggYusSds', 'title': 
"Why Time is One of Humanity's Greatest Inventions", 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '1.4M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6AWAoc_Lr0', 'title': 'Space Law-What Laws are There in Space?', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '1.5M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2H9KEcb74aA', 'title': "A Map Geek's Tour of the World #2", 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '248K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThNeIT7aceI', 'title': 'How the Layouts of Grocery Stores are Secretly Designed to Make You Spend More Money', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '953K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bg2VZIPfX0U', 'title': 'How to Create a Country', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '3.7M views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVB4TEeMcgA', 'title': "A Map Geek's Tour of the World", 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '405K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avh7ez858xM', 'title': 'The Messy Ethics of Self Driving Cars', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '461K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3jlFtBg0Y8', 'title': 'The Surprising Easternmost Point in the US', 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '213K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-ZskaqBshs', 'title': "Containerization: The Most Influential Invention That You've Never Heard Of", 'date_time': '6 years ago', 'views': '684K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nn-ym8y1_kw', 'title': 'The World is Shrinking', 'date_time': '7 years ago', 'views': '183K views'}, {'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LqqVfPduTs', 'title': 'How Marketers Manipulate Us: Psychological Manipulation in Advertising', 'date_time': '7 years ago', 'views': '458K views'}]

Total: 189
```

Answer (score 1):

#### If you don't have a YouTube Data API v3 developer key:

The following procedure requires you to have a Google account.

Go to: https://console.cloud.google.com/projectcreate

Click on the `CREATE` button.

Go to: https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/youtube.googleapis.com

Click on the `ENABLE` button.

Click on the `CREATE CREDENTIALS` button.

Choose the `Public data` option.

Click on the `NEXT` button.

Note the displayed `API Key` and continue reading.

#### If you have a YouTube Data API v3 developer key:

To get the videos of a given YouTube channel id (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73807243) if you don't know how to get the channel id of a given YouTube channel), replace its second character (`C`) to `U` to obtain its `uploads` playlist id and provide it as a `playlistId` to [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint.

This is a Python sample code listing videos of a given channel id (don't forget to replace `API_KEY` with your YouTube Data API v3 developer key):

```py
import requests
import json

CHANNEL_ID = 'UC07-dOwgza1IguKA86jqxNA'
PLAYLIST_ID = 'UU' + CHANNEL_ID[2:]
API_KEY = 'AIzaSy...'

URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems'
params = {
    'part': ','.join(['snippet']),
    'playlistId': PLAYLIST_ID,
    'maxResults' : 50,
    'key': API_KEY,
}

while True:
    response = requests.get(URL, params = params).json()
    print(json.dumps(response['items'], indent = 4))
    if not 'nextPageToken' in response:
        break
    params['pageToken'] = response['nextPageToken']
```

For documentation concerning the pagination, see [this webpage](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination).

Answer (score 0):

This process doesn't need any kind of use of api or channel id.
Getting video links with selenium python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import re
import json
import pyautogui

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

os.environ['PATH'] += r"PATH_chromedriver"


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("CHANNEL_URL")
driver.implicitly_wait(1)

video = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/ytdapp/div[1]/ytd-page-manager/ytd-browse/div[3]/ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer/tp-yt-app-header-layout/div/tp-yt-app-header/div[2]/tp-yt-app-toolbar/div/div/tp-yt-paper-tabs/div/div/tp-yt-paper-tab[2]')
video.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
pyautogui.vscroll(-10)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

html = driver.page_source
links = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html)

video_links = []
for link in links:
    video_links.append("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + link)

video_links = [*set(video_links)]
print(video_links)
print(len(video_links))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).