# How do I get YouTube latest video thumbnail from my channel?

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to get the latest YouTube video thumbnail from my channel? I just want to show 5 latest YouTube video thumbnails on my web site, then play the video in a pop up when I click on it.

Show 5 latest YouTube video thumbnail in my web site.

Comment: Following [my StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030) by paying attention to `item/snippet/thumbnails` will give you the thumbnails you are looking for.

Comment: hmm, i think i'll wait for another solution

Comment: @RahmanFaruqRajabiyansyahr which programming language you're using for this task?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes i'm using react js

Comment: @RahmanFaruqRajabiyansyahr it is possible, but, you have to [edit] your question and add what have you tried and/or researched so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $channelid=""; //write the channel id in quotes
    $xml = simplexml_load_file(sprintf('https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=%s', $channelid));
    $id = $xml->entry[0]->children('yt', true)->videoId[0]; //First Video ID
    $id2 = $xml->entry[0]->children('yt', true)->videoId[1]; //Second Video ID-Duplicate this up to 5
    $thumbimg="http://img.youtube.com/vi/$id/maxresdefault.jpg"; //First Video's thumnail
    $thumbimg2="http://img.youtube.com/vi/$id2/maxresdefault.jpg"; //Second Video's thumnail-Duplicate this up to 5
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).