# Youtube data API version 3 pagination continuation from previous day

Tags: youtube-api

I want to fetch all YouTube videos from a channel containing about 2k videos. Being limited by daily quota, I must continue paginated search from previous day using `nextPageToken`. Is this doable?

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?&key={key}&part=snippet&maxResults=20&order=viewCount&q=abc&type=video&videoDuration=long&videoType=movie&pageToken=Cd323A
```

Comment: Note that [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint can have a [`maxResults`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#maxResults) up to `50`, so with your 10,000 daily quota you can fetch 5,000 videos (and not 2,000 as you are currently doing), as the Search: list endpoint costs 100 quota per request. Use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030) to meet your needs, while only using 40 of quota.

Comment: Videos are not in a playlist, I'd like to get all the videos from a certain channel - btw my math was very poor obviously, thank you :)

Comment: All videos uploaded to a given channel are in an `uploads` playlist, as specified in the Stack Overflow link I mentioned, please have a longer look at it.