# Retrieve stats from a YouTube channel containing nearly 1,000 videos

Tags: windows, list, video, youtube

I would like to download a list of all the videos on a YouTube channel that has nearly 1,000 videos.  the output should be Title, Date Uploaded, Running Time, and Views.  I am a geriatric noob using a PC

I cannot find an answer to my question.  The potential answers are a couple of years old.  I have located the YouTube channel ID from the channels Play All source code.

Comment: What do you mean by *running time*?

Comment: Time i.e. mm:ss

Comment: Then using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030) and [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint should do the trick.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YouTube API to fetch all videos on a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel)