# Youtube API v3 missing results

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get the last 50 videos uploaded to a channel and the result is missing some of videos publicly available on the channel.

[Code I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRGWd.png)

It should provide with last 50 videos but it misses some of the videos in between.

Comment: You should properly provide the code here, not in links or images.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030) should solve your issue.