# how to get youtube videos of a channel without overloading daily quota DATA API 3

Tags: reactjs, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I currently work on a project where I need to showcase the 10 latest videos of the website owner, but using the youtube DATA API v3 but during testing I quickly ran out of the 10,000 assigned daily quota points, because I am using the "Search" request which costs 100 points, is there another way to get the video ids?
Using reactjs here is what I tried

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import useFetch from "../../hooks/useFetch"

export default function YoutubeEmbed() {

    const KEY = '[Redacted]'
    const CHANNEL_ID = '[Redacted]'
    const MAX_RESULTS = '10'
    const YOUTUBE_API_URL = `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=${CHANNEL_ID}&maxResults=${MAX_RESULTS}&order=date&key=${KEY}`
    const SCALE_FATOR = 1.5
    const [currentVideoIndex,setCurrentVideoIndex] = useState(0)
    const [videos, setVideos] = useState([])
    const { loading, error, value } = useFetch(
        YOUTUBE_API_URL,
        {},
        [])

    const getVideos = () => {
        let items = value?.items
        let videos = items?.map(((video) => {
            return {
                id: video.id.videoId,
                title: video.snippet.title,
                description: video.snippet.description,
                thumbnails: video.snippet.thumbnails
            }
        }))
        return videos
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!loading) {
            if (!error) {
                setVideos(getVideos())
            } else console.log(error);
        }
    }, [loading])



    return (
        <>
            <div className="youtube-current-video">
                <iframe
                    src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videos[currentVideoIndex]?.id}`}
                    allowFullScreen
                    frameborder="0"
                    width={`${480 * SCALE_FATOR}px`}
                    height={`${270 * SCALE_FATOR}px`}
                />
            </div>

        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030) solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Benjamin Loison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7123660/benjamin-loison), this was answered in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74578175/getting-video-links-from-youtube-channel-in-python-selenium/74579030#74579030), in order to fix it I used the youtube-data-api V3's [PlaylistItems request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with playlistID = ChannelID with the 2nd character (`C`) changed to `U`.