# Missing videos on the youtube API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube data API and it was working before but in the last week or so every time I retrieve videos ordered by date it is always missing one video or more and I can't know the reason;
this is an example of the call:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=${youtube}&key=${api_key}&type=video&order=date&maxResults=15`

I have tried trying other channels but the problem is the same and even more videos are missing in other channels.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030) should solve your problem.