# YouTube JS API v3. Get four last videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to get the latest videos from a channel. For this I use this URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key=${apiKey}&channelId=${espacioSutilChannelID}&maxResults=4&order=date
```

I receive four videos, but they are not the last ones, why? How can I receive the latest videos?

The channel is this: https://www.youtube.com/@Espaciosutil/videos

The received JSON is this. It can be verified that the JSON results do not match the last videos of the channel:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "YLx4MtKRajR1pi0SsHeY_PgBpn8",
  "nextPageToken": "CAQQAA",
  "regionCode": "ES",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1073,
    "resultsPerPage": 4
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "ibQqD0y_7TR1b53OUcMtESa2eng",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "7TMjENsCtWg"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-06-28T18:50:22Z",
        "channelId": "UCBHahOd3MSYL2ONV17F1XGQ",
        "title": "CONVERSACIONES CON DIOS - Libro I. Capítulo 1 (15ª parte)",
        "description": "Grabaciones de las sesiones de Iván Prospector de explicación de la información revelada en la serie de libros de ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7TMjENsCtWg/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7TMjENsCtWg/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7TMjENsCtWg/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Espacio Sutil",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2023-06-28T18:50:22Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "bqcXP8NVeSA7UpaYHPgrJvtZ10E",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "CTxo_UdAdWc"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-06-27T20:25:23Z",
        "channelId": "UCBHahOd3MSYL2ONV17F1XGQ",
        "title": "UN CURSO DE MILAGROS - 12.VI - La visión de Cristo (1 a 7 de 7)",
        "description": "Grabaciones de las sesiones de Iván Prospector de la serie de lectura acompañada de Un Curso de Milagros. Se pretende la ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CTxo_UdAdWc/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CTxo_UdAdWc/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CTxo_UdAdWc/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Espacio Sutil",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2023-06-27T20:25:23Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "I51wNWmW448hKimAAsuyr1-0ABY",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "wS9Bw9K6l-8"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-06-27T20:08:59Z",
        "channelId": "UCBHahOd3MSYL2ONV17F1XGQ",
        "title": "NUESTRAS VOCES - (6ª) - Viajes astrales y sueños lúcidos",
        "description": "Grabaciones del programa de divulgación terapéutica espiritual de Espacio Sutil NUESTRAS VOCES - Jessica Pernett - María ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wS9Bw9K6l-8/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wS9Bw9K6l-8/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wS9Bw9K6l-8/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Espacio Sutil",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2023-06-27T20:08:59Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "DQBz6HWuhyX6YBCckhaPLABY6YA",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "DcnHUhl6ruo"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-06-27T20:10:30Z",
        "channelId": "UCBHahOd3MSYL2ONV17F1XGQ",
        "title": "UN CURSO DE AMOR - TAP.9 (1) - Dar y recibir (1 a 10 de 16)",
        "description": "Grabaciones de las sesiones de Iván Prospector de explicación de la información revelada por Jesús, a través de Mari Perron y ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DcnHUhl6ruo/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DcnHUhl6ruo/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DcnHUhl6ruo/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Espacio Sutil",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2023-06-27T20:10:30Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030) solves your problem.

Comment: Could you give me more info about how to find the solution? I've read that answer but I cant find it.

Comment: The `items` returned in my answer are chronologically ordered which solves your problem, right?