# Missing videos in the search endpoint in Youtube data API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

There is a channel where I want to access its uploads and show it in my Website which is built using Vanilla JS; so basically when accessing the search endpoint it works correctly and shows the videos, but there is like 20+ video missing, the API manages to not include a major part of August's and all of July's videos and only show 3 videos in August (which are the last 3 which were uploaded) and June videos (from date 8/19 till date 6/26)!
[JSON which shows the month worth gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICWfp.jpg)

**Here is what I am dealing with:**

GET [https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC7AbKZa30XPMInZIsViiBOQ&maxResults=20&order=date&safeSearch=none&type=video&videoCaption=any&videoDefinition=any&videoDimension=any&videoDuration=any&videoEmbeddable=any&videoLicense=any&videoPaidProductPlacement=any&videoSyndicated=any&videoType=any&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC7AbKZa30XPMInZIsViiBOQ&maxResults=20&order=date&safeSearch=none&type=video&videoCaption=any&videoDefinition=any&videoDimension=any&videoDuration=any&videoEmbeddable=any&videoLicense=any&videoPaidProductPlacement=any&videoSyndicated=any&videoType=any&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)

I passed these parameters (perhaps any of them made or fixes this problem):

- order:date
- safeSearch: none
- type: video
- videoCaption: any
- videoDefinition: any
- videoDimension: any
- videoDuration: any
- videoEmbeddable: any
- videoLicense:any
- videoPaidProductPlacement: any
- videoSyndicated: any
- videoType: any

*Any suggested edits to this question to make it better and more clear would be appreciated*

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030) solves your issue.

Comment: I do have the key Mr. Benjamin and as is stated in my question every works fine, but there some missing videos from date 8/19 till date 6/26

Comment: I perfectly understood your issue and I repeat that proceeding  as I mentioned with [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint solves your [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint issue.

Comment: I've got you, so solution is: use playlistItems:list instead? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks man!, problem got solved and it only costs 1 quotas unlike search endpoint