# Selenium WebDriver not scrolling on YouTube page for web scraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, youtube, webdriver

'm using Selenium WebDriver to scrape data from a YouTube channel page, but I'm encountering issues with scrolling. After processing 30 videos, YouTube seems to load more videos as the page is scrolled down. However, my code isn't automatically scrolling to load more videos but sometime it automatically duplicating the after every 30 videos. How can I make Selenium scroll properly and scrap better on a YouTube page for web scraping without API?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Function to scroll to the bottom of the page to load the videos
def scroll_to_bottom(driver):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")

# Function to extract video info such as comment, likes, titles, views and etc.
def extract_video_info(driver, channel_url, max_videos=100):
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(channel_url)

    video_info_list = []
    video_count = 0

    try:
        while video_count < max_videos:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@id="video-title-link"]')))
            video_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@id="video-title-link"]')
            for video_link in video_links:
                video_info = {}
                try:
                    # Getting the video title
                    video_title = video_link.get_attribute("title")
                    
                    # Get the video link's href attribute
                    video_href = video_link.get_attribute("href")
                    
                    # Opening the video link I took into a new tab
                    driver.execute_script(f"window.open('{video_href}','_blank');")
                    
                    # Switch to the new tab
                    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
                    
                    # Wait for the video description to load
                    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
                    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="description"]/yt-formatted-string')))
                    description = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="description"]/yt-formatted-string')
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", description)
                    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="segmented-like-button"]/ytd-toggle-button-renderer/yt-button-shape/button')))
                    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="info-container"]')))
                    
                    # Extract information
                    likes = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="segmented-like-button"]/ytd-toggle-button-renderer/yt-button-shape/button').text.strip()
                    info_container = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="info-container"]')
                    info_text = info_container.text
                    
                    # Extract views
                    views = info_text.split(" views")[0].strip()
                    
                    # Extract date if it exists, else set to "Not found"
                    date = "Not found"
                    date_split = info_text.split(" views ")
                    if len(date_split) > 1:
                        date = date_split[1].split("\n")[0].strip()
                    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="comments"]')))
                    
                    # Extract comment count
                    comment_count_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="comments"]')
                    comment_count = comment_count_element.text.strip()
                    video_info['Title'] = video_title
                    video_info['Likes'] = likes
                    video_info['Views'] = views
                    video_info['Date'] = date
                    video_info['Comments'] = comment_count
                    
                    # Add the video info to the list
                    video_info_list.append(video_info)
                   
                    driver.close()
                    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
                    
                    # Increment the video counter
                    video_count += 1
                    
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error extracting video info: {e}")
            
            # Scroll to load more videos
            scroll_to_bottom(driver)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    
    # Close the WebDriver when done
    driver.quit()

    return video_info_list

edge_driver_path = r'C:/Users/hp/msedgedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=edge_driver_path)
channel_url = "https://www.youtube.com/@UnfoldDataScience/videos"
max_videos_to_scrape = 400

video_info_list = extract_video_info(driver, channel_url, max_videos_to_scrape)

for i, video_info in enumerate(video_info_list):
    print(f"Video {i+1}:")
    print(f"Title: {video_info['Title']}")
    print(f"Likes: {video_info['Likes']}")
    print(f"Views: {video_info['Views']}")
    print(f"Date: {video_info['Date']}")
    print(f"Comments: {video_info['Comments']}")
    print("\n---\n")
```

My output stops right here:
Video 28:
Likes: 41
Views: 1.1K
Date: 5 months ago  #sqlserver

---

Video 29:
Likes: 41
Views: 766
Date: 5 months ago  #ai #BardVsChatgpt #bardai

---

Video 30:
Likes: 79
Views: 1.7K
Date: 5 months ago  Amazon Web Services (AWS) for Data Science

After processing I am getting 194 duplicate rows, and only 104 orignal rows. I dont understand if it is the scrolling problem or something else
The code does not go further after 30 videos. I cannot use the API. Also I would appreciate if i get the proper video description code if i click on video description. The date and the views are shown properly but that code does not work. My task is to read all the video data in the channel from 10 September 2023 to 10 September 2021 as you seen the output the description don't give the proper date while if I click on description I can see this

```
1,228 views  6 Sept 2023  #businessanalysis #ai #datascience
```

So how can I do that

Comment: Why not using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) with a method like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030)?

Comment: I am not allowed to use Youtube API

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues that I assume you're going to run into with your code but to answer your initial problem, it looks like the height of `window.body` on YouTube is 0, and the whole page's content is inside a child element `<ytd-app>` that has position absolute and is basically acting like the body element.

To fix this, replace the scrolling js script in your `scroll_to_bottom()` function with `window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight)`

The other issue I see is that, assuming you're trying to open every video on a channel page, you need to loop over the videos that load after scrolling. But right now your code looks like this:

1. Get channel page
2. Get first batch of 30 loaded video links
3. Loop over each link, scraping data
4. If the total number of videos scraped is %30, scroll to bottom of page
5. Exit Loop
6. Exit App

So you never do anything with the data loaded from scrolling to the bottom.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a bunch Because of your help. I was able to cross almost 117 videos. Big thanks!