# I don't get the latest video from a Channel with Youtube API

Tags: video, request, youtube-api

I am new to coding with the Youtube API. When I run my code, it doesn't always give me the latest video from [my selected Channel](https://www.youtube.com/@Joyca/videos) (the target video was uploaded on: 03-Sep-2023).

Example of code that I'm using:

```py
request_videos = youtube.search().list(
order='date',
channelId = identifiant, part='snippet', 
type='video', 
maxResults=1
)
```

This is the returned result from the API:

```py
JOYCA
['kind': 'youtube#searchListResponse', 
'etag': '02zCYj4jrMn08FxGFug-fuBXNLO', 
'nextPageToken': 'CAEQAA', 'regionCode': 'FR', 
'pageInfo': ('totalResults': 392, 'results PerPage': 1), 
'items': [{'kind': 'youtube#searchResult', 'etag': 'kE6y5R30Aoa TuP53yKyvW5zsAo', 'id': ['kind': 'youtube#video', 'videoId': 'MrE3zS0ecdE'}, 'snippet': [ 'publishedAt': '2023-08-27T12:20:20Z', 'channelId': 'UCow21Gnug113Xazkrc5jM_Q', 'title': 'TIK TOK M&#39;A FAIT ACHETER CA ! #5 (C&#39;est une folie ça)', 'description : 'Vous pouvez télécharger REVOLUT gratuitement avec mon lien : https://revolut.onelink.me/z41F/joyca Vous pourrez débloquer les ...', 'thumbnails': ('default': ['url' : 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MrE3zS0ecdE/default.jpg', 'width': 120, 'height': 90), 'medium': ('url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MrE3zS0ecdE/mqdefault.jpg', 'width': 320, 'h eight: 180), 'high': {'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MrE3z50ecdE/hqdefault.jpg', 'width': 480, 'height': 360}}, 'channelTitle': 'JOYCA", 'liveBroadcastContent': 'none ', 'publishTime': '2023-08-27T12:20:20Z"}}]}
```

**editor's note:** The above text is auto-extracted from [this provided image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQGSk.png) (*ie:* it's added here for illustration purposes only, it cannot *(and does not need to)* be tested).

- Expected (correct) "latest video" result:
  [image]

- Actually returned (by API) code result: 
  [image]

**What I've tried:** 
I tried to check if it's not a latency issue related to the API, but it's not.
I modified the requests but still nothing.

I tested with another ID on different channels, and it's the same issue, even though for some, I have no account/user problems.

I checked the quotas, just in case, but there's nothing there either.

**Expected result:** 
What I would like is to be able to get the latest videos that come out, maybe not instantly but at least with a maximum delay of 3 hours to 1 day

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030) solves your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Video Links from Youtube Channel in Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74578175/getting-video-links-from-youtube-channel-in-python-selenium)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit] your question. Code and error messages should be written as text, not images. You can leave the images as a supporting info.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I don't get the latest video from a Channel when using the Youtube API"*
>
> *"What I would like is to be able to get the latest videos that come out..."*

**Possible Solution:**

I'm not sure what programming language you are using, but if
you can use it to load/read text from some external `https` links then (instead of using the Youtube API) you can try:

Get the Channel's XML feed (is not JSON)

https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCow2IGnug1l3Xazkrc5jM_Q

Then...

If you know how to parse an XML-formatted data then do that with loaded result.

Or else just use your programming language's **String** functions to extract the text from first text of "`<entry>`" up to first text of  "`</entry>`". 
That will extract the details of the latest video. From there you can extract text of the thumbnail's link or extract text for the title, etc.