# Optimizing Youtube-api calls

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using discord.js running in Node.js to create a Discord bot that checks if a YouTube channel has a new video on it. I'm using the API to perform these checks every half an hour. Before the day ends, my API calls run out, and I can no longer check, resulting in a large JSON error response.

In my code, it fetches the information and stores it in a database. When it checks the YouTube channel again, if the video is new, it records it in the database and publishes the video.

```
> const { Client, EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");
> const axios = require("axios");
> require("dotenv").config();
> const key = process.env.youtube;
> const channelAnnouncement = "1144157374773473403";
> 
> const channelIds = [
>   "UCZ-yZV4JKOewGZAJSqs2V0w", // Por um punhado de dados.
>   "UCF1BfG8XJb9m6g96vn76G6A", // variedados
>   "UCCkIJHK5KYpWb58YyAqTWKg", // GURPS na veia
>   "UC4-7okrLZK2sfwINnqZNVog", // Chris Normand
>   "UCRhm02S_o1oktdjfj6JTlTA" // n sei se eu quero isso....
> Adicione mais IDs de canal conforme necessário
> ];
> 
> const Video = require("../schema/youtubeSchema");
> 
> async function youtube(client) {
> try {
> for (const channelId of channelIds) {
> const video = await getLatestVideo(channelId);
> 
> Extrair informações do vídeo
> const videoTitle = video.snippet.title;
> const videoUrl = `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${video.id.videoId}`;
> const channelTitle = video.snippet.channelTitle;
> const videoDescription = video.snippet.description; // Adicionando descrição do vídeo
> const channelThumbnail = video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url; // Miniatura do canal
> const videoThumbnail =
> video.snippet.thumbnails.maxres?.url ||
> video.snippet.thumbnails.high?.url ||
> video.snippet.thumbnails.medium?.url ||
> video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
> 
> Verificar se o vídeo já existe na base de dados
> const existingVideo = await Video.findOne({ videoUrl });
> 
> if (!existingVideo) {
> Se não existir, adicione-o à base de dados
> const newVideo = new Video({
> videoTitle,
> videoUrl,
> channelTitle,
> videoThumbnail,
> videoDescription,
> channelThumbnail,
>         });
> await newVideo.save();
> console.log("  Novo vídeo adicionado à base de dados:");
> console.log("Nome do Canal:", channelTitle);
> const embed = new EmbedBuilder(); // Certifique-se de que está usando a classe EmbedBuilder corretamente
> embed
>           .setColor(0x5506ce)
>           .setDescription(`${videoDescription}`)
>           .setThumbnail(`${channelThumbnail}`)
>           .setURL(`${videoUrl}`)
>           .setTitle(`${videoTitle}`)
>           .setImage(`${videoThumbnail}`);
> 
> Enviar a mensagem para o canal de anúncios
> const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelAnnouncement);
> 
> channel.send({ embeds: [embed] }).catch((error) => {
> console.error("⛔ Erro ao enviar embed:", error);
>         });
> console.log(" Vídeo enviado.");
> else {
> Se já existir, compare o título para verificar se o vídeo é diferente
> if (existingVideo.videoTitle !== videoTitle) {
> Atualize o vídeo na base de dados
> existingVideo.videoTitle = videoTitle;
> existingVideo.save();
> else {
> console.log(
> Vídeo já existe na base de dados e não foi alterado."
>           );
>         }
>       }
>     }
> catch (error) {
> console.error("⛔ Erro na função principal:", error);
>   }
> }
> 
> async function getLatestVideo(channelId) {
> const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${key}&channelId=${channelId}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=1`;
> const response = await axios.get(url);
> const latestVideo = response.data.items[0];
> return latestVideo;
> }
> 
> module.exports = {
> youtube,
> };
> 
> 


the timer is in the main.j triggering in 30 minutes cycle. 






My questions are:

1- Is there a way to optimize and use the API more effectively to perform more checks throughout the day?
2- When the JSON error is returned, how can I do it in a way that makes it easier to read the error content?
```

Comment: Use the 1 quota cost [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint instead of the 100 quota cost [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030).

Comment: The problem with using the playlist id will be if the content creator creates a video in a new playlist. Am I right?

Comment: The `uploads` playlist isn't *manually* modifiable by the content creator, except by *deleting* or uploading videos on its channel. So this playlist contains its actual public videos, hence I don't see any problem.

Comment: Ok, so the playlist contains all videos from the channel! I got it, thanks you.

Comment: I'm sorry to dwell on this matter for too long, but a new issue has arisen. The recommended method works, but I still need to retrieve the CHANNEL's thumbnail as requested by a client. My main concern is token economy. Is there any way for me to retrieve this information using fewer tokens?

Comment: Concerning reducing quota usage for checking new uploads consider [Subscribing to Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications).