# Youtube V3 API New Video in Channel - Python

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

How can I automatically get a video from a YouTube channel, when a new video is uploaded, using python?

I'm using YouTube V3 API, and I don't know if I should use the `API` method or `OAUTH`.

This is my first time using this library, and I didn't find any tutorials on YouTube.

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=python+youtube+api+%2Bchannel+update

Comment: Consider [this YouTube Data API v3 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030) or [this one](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications).

Comment: Please show some code you are trying.