# Get youtube notifications

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am starting a project and would like some guidance on it. I will use discord.js in node to create a bot that returns notifications about the latest videos from some channels selected by the user. I need it to return the title of the video, description, image, channel thumbnail, and description.

I would like to know the best method for this while spending as few tokens as possible. I believe that the scrapping method is illegal. Thank you very much for the guidance.

Comment: These are the two most efficient methods: [playlist based](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030) and [web hook based](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications).