# incomplete data from the fetch result using google data API

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-data-api

I want to retrieve the last 50 video data from a channel using appscript and google data API v3. the logger successfully shows 50 data from today to June. but many video data in November are not indexed.

Here's the script I made

```
var apiKey = 'my API';
var channelId = 'UCAoy6rzhSf4ydcYjJw3WoVg'; 

function fetchRecentVideos() {
  var apiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';

  var videos = [];

  var params = {
    'part': 'snippet',
    'channelId': channelId,
    'type': 'video',
    'maxResults': 50,
    'order': 'date', 
    'key': apiKey
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl + '?' + encodeParams(params));
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  for (var i = 0; i < result.items.length; i++) {
    var video = result.items[i].snippet;
    Logger.log('Video Title:'+ video.title);
    Logger.log('Published Date:'+ video.publishedAt);
    Logger.log('--------------------');
  }
}

function encodeParams(params) {
  return Object.keys(params)
    .map(function (key) {
      return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
    })
    .join('&');
}
```

Comment: When I tested your showing script, the value of `publishedAt` of the 1st item is `2023-11-28T17:09:25Z`. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your current situation of `the logger successfully shows 50 data from today to June.`. I apologize for this. But, for example, when you add `publishedAfter: "2023-11-01T00:00:00Z"` to `params` and test it again, what result will you obtain? I guessed that `publishedAfter` might be close to your expected result. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

Comment: when I followed your advice to use publishedAfter and publishedBefore, all videos are indexed completely. so what's wrong with my code? 'order': 'date',?

Comment: Thank you for testing it. From `when I followed your advice to use publishedAfter and publishedBefore, all videos are indexed completely.`, as the next step, when you remove `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore`, and you test your showing script, what result will you obtain? Your issue of `the logger successfully shows 50 data from today to June.` will be replicated, again?

Comment: yes, it replicated again after I deleted the published... some videos are not indexed as in the first problem

Comment: Thank you for testing it. I think that your showing script is correct. Because when I tested your showing script, the value of `publishedAt` of the 1st item is `2023-11-28T17:09:25Z`. But, from your reply, I'm worried that other factors might be related to your current situation. For example, when you create a new Google Apps Script project and test your showing script again, what result will you obtain?

Comment: still with the same results. but when I just add publishedAfter, everything is indexed completely. but when only using publishedBefore, the results are still the same. 
thanks for the help

Comment: Thank you for testing it again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the reason for your current issue. Because I cannot replicate your situation. I deeply apologize for my very very poor skill. In that case, how about adding only `publishedBefore: new Date().toISOString()` to `params`? By this, the items before the time of execution of the script are obtained. How about this?

Comment: By the way, when your issue is resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030)?

Comment: Google Apps Script supports only JavaScript for scripting. Python is not directly supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to add publishedAfter to the pharameter, so the output will come out all complete and in the order of the most recent.
this doesn't work if using publishedBefore

```
var params = {
    'part': 'snippet',
    'channelId': channelId,
    'type': 'video',
    'maxResults': 50,
    'order': 'date',
    'publishedAfter': '2010-01-01T00:00:00Z',
    'key': apiKey
  };
```