# Youtube API not scraping all videos in channel

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube-data-api

I am trying to scrape all video IDs from a Youtube channel, but the API appears to randomly skip certain videos when looping through the pages. For instance, the channel provided below is for The Kelly Clarkson Show - which has posted over 5k videos since 2019. But the code below only scrapes video IDs for 511 videos. The Youtube Data API limit is not the problem, and videos appear to be skipped at random. It is also not an issue of private/unlisted videos.

Here is the code I used:

```
channel_id = 'UCmSQ47G2NHhcjRAm9Px6R3g'
video_ids = []
next_page_token = None
published_after = datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'

while True:
  try:
    request = youtube.search().list(
        part='id',
        channelId=channel_id,
        safeSearch='none',
        publishedAfter=published_after,
        order='date',
        pageToken=next_page_token,
        maxResults=50,
    )

    response = request.execute()

    for item in response['items']:
        if 'videoId' in item['id']:
            video_ids.append(item['id']['videoId'])

    next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')

    if not next_page_token:
      break

  except HttpError as e:
      if e.resp.status == 403 and b'quota' in e.content.lower():
          print("YouTube API daily limit reached. Stopping the loop.")
          break
      else:
          raise
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030) is the solution to this issue and [here](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/4) is the reason of this issue.