# youtube/v3/commentThreads endpoint ends up with 403 error code, it refers to "disabled comments"

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When calling the `youtube/v3/commentThreads` endpoint on Youtube Data API for a specific channel we are getting 100% of the time:

```
"allThreadsRelatedToChannelId": "UCoBh-XkiQeyKCSNFUsF4BGg",
```

```json
{   
    "code": 403,    
    "message": "The video identified by the <code><a href=\"/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId\">videoId</a></code> parameter has disabled comments.",    
    "errors": [ 
        { 
            "message": "The video identified by the <code><a href=\"/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId\">videoId</a></code> parameter has disabled comments.",            
            "domain": "youtube.commentThread",          
            "reason": "commentsDisabled",           
            "location": "videoId",          
            "locationType": "parameter"         
        }   
    ] 
}
```

We believed that this may be caused by Video Specific and Channel Level specific disabling of comments, but we were unable to reproduce it on a test profile after trying out all settings we could found out:

Setting 1 - My Videos > Settings > Community > Comments on your channel On/Off

Setting 2 - My Videos > Details (Specific Video) > SHOW MORE > #Comments and ratings

Even after meddling with these settings the error would still not be reproducible.

On this channel (`UCoBh-XkiQeyKCSNFUsF4BGg`) specifically for the following videos it yields the error in case of the video with disabled comments. While on our test channel it does not.

`JvetBp5l-GA` (Has comments) -> Yields comments normally

`uuuWjURsJF0` (Comments disabled) -> Yields same error as above

`KO3Trt0YgcY` (No comments) -> Yields empty list When doing the `youtube/v3/commentThreads` call with `maxResults = 1` the error still is yielded as well.

Both profiles we are using their own tokens for this call.

What can be a possible cause of this issue?

Comment: I faced this issue in the past. Personally when I notice such a comments disabled channel, I list all its videos thanks to [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030) and retrieve comments on all this channel videos not having their comments disabled.