How to get last videos from YouTube channel
This request found some old videos but it must find new 5 videos.
"publishedAt": "2023-02-15T01:35:11Z"
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={my_api_key}&channelId=UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=5
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "jwmpvUGSSAJ-HqQDhqwcn7y_yng",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "DEgt25yYidY"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-02-15T01:35:11Z",
        "channelId": "UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw",
        "title": "Gordon Ramsey VS Woman in COMPLETE denial",

There are a lot of new videos on the channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw
I deleted '&order=date' and found old videos from 2016. What about 2024y?
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={my_api_key}&channelId=UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw&part=snippet,id&maxResults=5

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030

I just tried it with 'search' and order by date. If you select 50 results it will only show older videos from 2023 as newest videos. But if you use 200 results (with pagination) you will see the newest videos.
Search:
https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list
