# Youtube API v3 not giving channel data

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been using youtube API from a time now but some recent changes in the API, are breaking the code.
I was able to get the channel id from channel username through this API call :

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername={channelUsername}&key={key}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=%7BchannelUsername%7D&key=%7Bkey%7D)

But due to recent changes, this API is not returning any data for channel id.
There's no updated documentation on this yet.

How can this be resolved apart from using any third party API?

Comment: With what `{channelUsername}` are you trying? With [`WHO`](https://www.youtube.com/user/WHO) https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?forUsername=WHO&key={key} returns correctly `UC07-dOwgza1IguKA86jqxNA` on my end. Maybe you are like many others disturbed by [the many different custom URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73807243).

Comment: It returns data for channels with large subscriber count, for other channels like: RoCarsTV, DavidTeatherCodes, Brotomotiv. Youtube channel urls in this format : "https://www.youtube.com/user/badabunOficial" works fine but not in this new format (seems to be changed recently) : "https://www.youtube.com/@Brotomotiv". A new character '@' has been added in the url.

Comment: [As mentioned previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73807243), then your question is a duplicated of [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74323173).