# YouTube: How to search for the channels with given exact channel name?

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I want to search for the YouTube channels with the given channel name.

Exact match with double quotation doesn't satisfy my need.

For example, when the given channel name is "ABC", I only want to retrieve channels with the name "ABC", and I don't want to retrieve channels with names such as "ABCD" or "ABCReadyGo" or "HiABC" or etc.

How can I do it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73807243) on a similar question will interest you.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75374713/12511801) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75325524/12511801) - in your code, you have to compare the results and use only those channels where the name matches with your search term - i.e the channel name you want to get.