# How to handle @ in the users name?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am using `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/` v3 of the Youtube API which works perfectly with examples such as `id=UCe5TCe6L-uYM106WzSIKuYQ` or `forUsername=unisportlife` in the calling URL. However I have now come across youtube users with an `@` sign in their URL and have tried both `forUsername` and `id` and neither seem to pull through the Video feed. How do we tackle that in V3?

On further investigation, `UCZ0SxS_c5V0mPgNMyWgVyig` actually is equal to `@ModernDayGK`. When I use the UCZ with `id` I get video results, but switch this to `%40ModernDayGK` (with `id` or `forUsername` and I get:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "RuuXzTIr0OoDqI4S0RU6n4FqKEM",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  }
}
```

So clearly something has changed ?

Comment: have you tried url-encoding the value?

Comment: I hadn't, have now but still no success

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807) on a similar question.

Comment: It could be me - in that they don't actually have any channels setup and that is my go-to endpoint! Just trying to see if i can access videos.

Comment: Actually - I'm updating my question because I've found an anomaly.

Comment: Handles aren't supported (even if they are URL encoded) by YouTube Data API v3 (cf the link I shared above). Your question `So clearly something has changed?` is unclear as you don't present previous working example contrarily to the same one not working nowadays.

Comment: @Antony how do you obtained the `forUsername` values? - in YouTube Data API, it's not documented the use with handles, so, I rather user `channel_id` as parameter for the search - as I show in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75325524/12511801)