# How can I get YouTube channel ID using channel name URL?

Tags: javascript, axios, youtube-data-api

I have made a program where users provide a YouTube channel URL and in return I will show the user its channel ID.

Like if someone puts URL like: https://youtube.com/@AndreoBee then I will return its channel ID.

```js
const axios = require('axios');

async function getChannelId(url) {
  const channelUsername = url.split('/').pop();
  const response = await axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=${channelUsername}&key=myapi`);

  if (response.data.items.length === 0) {
    throw new Error(`Channel not found: ${url}`);
  }

  console.log(response.data.items[0].id);
}

getChannelId('https://www.youtube.com/@AndreoBee');
```

Output:

> /home/runner/ytcheck/index.js:7   if (response.data.items.length ===
> 0) {
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
> at getChannelId (/home/runner/ytcheck/index.js:7:27)

Comment: The error says that `response.data.items` is undefined. Check the response is what you think it is.

Comment: That's the main problem it is not giving items field in response.data

Comment: YouTube official APIs don't support channel handles, duplicate with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74323173).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following node.js script

```
var https = require('https');

var url = "https://www.youtube.com/@adnantoky"

https.get(url, function (res) {
    var data = '';
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        let arr = data.split('channel_id=');
        console.log("Channel ID:", arr[1].slice(0, 24));
    });
}).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative - using YouTube Data API -  could be:

- Use the [search:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=es&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A10%2C%22q%22%3A%22AndreoBee%22%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22US%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22channel%22%5D%7D) endpoint for *search channels that matches with the criteria* - in this case, the name/handle of the channel.

Example:

> Search channels named "AndreoBee" - you're getting this value in the `channelUsername` variable in your code:

URL:

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&maxResults=10&q=AndreoBee&type=channel&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

Response:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "K2G-sXJIFnrJFyMaoDvw4XMBym4",
  "nextPageToken": "CAoQAA",
  "regionCode": "CO",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 6740,
    "resultsPerPage": 10
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "oeyNublAqxB8TOEQbtwA4k0Oqgs",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UCjdjyjdcdmldCK5XuuWbn1A"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-01-21T15:12:27Z",
        "channelId": "UCjdjyjdcdmldCK5XuuWbn1A",
        "title": "AndreoBee",
        "description": "I am a Youtuber.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AL5GRJW_gCXDGAviuBWh0GwUO4V5Ia4JNYzC0Mp9bYhigA=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AL5GRJW_gCXDGAviuBWh0GwUO4V5Ia4JNYzC0Mp9bYhigA=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AL5GRJW_gCXDGAviuBWh0GwUO4V5Ia4JNYzC0Mp9bYhigA=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "AndreoBee",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-01-21T15:12:27Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "iG8-NwZab0LLB245AY2MkJ6pexI",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UC2Xpzteb9hbamaeEHZRxPCw"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-11-27T07:07:23Z",
        "channelId": "UC2Xpzteb9hbamaeEHZRxPCw",
        "title": "AndreoBee",
        "description": "This is my backup channel guys ;)",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AL5GRJVgMinAIKpEHBPjM2Os8fHFKcsxtTyTIflqTwVR=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AL5GRJVgMinAIKpEHBPjM2Os8fHFKcsxtTyTIflqTwVR=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AL5GRJVgMinAIKpEHBPjM2Os8fHFKcsxtTyTIflqTwVR=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "AndreoBee",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-11-27T07:07:23Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "3X2zApHnPAW2p2awm4tIETn9ybI",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UCp6iawa7GPTszoJxOiG5d_Q"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-03-15T16:19:39Z",
        "channelId": "UCp6iawa7GPTszoJxOiG5d_Q",
        "title": "AndreoBee",
        "description": "Welcome my ARS GAMING YouTube channel I am uploading full movies or shorts and how to download movies on my YouTube ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/Z2CC1zWbsD3k-z9cX0RlPBstKELZw0_sUgFPggIt-DhVkJWL8iJG8pCLizxr3StB8lbZX9PT7U8=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/Z2CC1zWbsD3k-z9cX0RlPBstKELZw0_sUgFPggIt-DhVkJWL8iJG8pCLizxr3StB8lbZX9PT7U8=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/Z2CC1zWbsD3k-z9cX0RlPBstKELZw0_sUgFPggIt-DhVkJWL8iJG8pCLizxr3StB8lbZX9PT7U8=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "AndreoBee",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2021-03-15T16:19:39Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "VHP4HsDcIiETPleAWN0cSC7fvbE",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UCWLY3sMMYHH3-9xQ2lhFj8g"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2022-06-27T01:08:10Z",
        "channelId": "UCWLY3sMMYHH3-9xQ2lhFj8g",
        "title": "AndreoBee",
        "description": "Hii guus i am Andreo I hope you like my videos and please support me guys thank you have a good day.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/bHaKoA8QZnZSJXfmK7udtrzxmpCOOhpTHIoP_RQUD2KLv9qNXtLLKY_bewbaQGdfZGIPCcO9Ag=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/bHaKoA8QZnZSJXfmK7udtrzxmpCOOhpTHIoP_RQUD2KLv9qNXtLLKY_bewbaQGdfZGIPCcO9Ag=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/bHaKoA8QZnZSJXfmK7udtrzxmpCOOhpTHIoP_RQUD2KLv9qNXtLLKY_bewbaQGdfZGIPCcO9Ag=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "AndreoBee",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2022-06-27T01:08:10Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "01NvBqsdnNimHwnwHnGkeVOhJ-8",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UC3yVv5tuR3tBcVf97j33mQQ"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-12-12T14:31:22Z",
        "channelId": "UC3yVv5tuR3tBcVf97j33mQQ",
        "title": "Andreobee",
        "description": "Describe the game All best game for play on Android in 2GB ram and 3GB phone.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AL5GRJXval25GhQFpbqoFgQXvWBol5aqf4ZCOluMMOe-=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AL5GRJXval25GhQFpbqoFgQXvWBol5aqf4ZCOluMMOe-=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AL5GRJXval25GhQFpbqoFgQXvWBol5aqf4ZCOluMMOe-=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Andreobee",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-12-12T14:31:22Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "B5TOx4aFyuua9eQVa-QBbKDjIng",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UCBR0QlbTtbT52oFmmDZIamw"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2022-02-01T14:44:18Z",
        "channelId": "UCBR0QlbTtbT52oFmmDZIamw",
        "title": "AndreoBee",
        "description": "",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/TfGkwtvsAvJdWnMOdRLRn2HKRvnVj872dxLZdZ_ghFwpF4SrY2BqBwJ3syc1V6HLL3LyJiSABQ=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/TfGkwtvsAvJdWnMOdRLRn2HKRvnVj872dxLZdZ_ghFwpF4SrY2BqBwJ3syc1V6HLL3LyJiSABQ=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/TfGkwtvsAvJdWnMOdRLRn2HKRvnVj872dxLZdZ_ghFwpF4SrY2BqBwJ3syc1V6HLL3LyJiSABQ=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "AndreoBee",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2022-02-01T14:44:18Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "t04J8v3aRhQhmFsyv54ddTXGDMQ",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UCBvdbv05Cb4Ulf_PlunMJtA"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-08-12T06:59:40Z",
        "channelId": "UCBvdbv05Cb4Ulf_PlunMJtA",
        "title": "AndreoBee",
        "description": "",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/S3J1R-s_P481lUpBULskSiQ0Pv-Z_iLnE_YrZ10OL1cydCFx6a1aOXvRJskMxY-gVpa8cqwuzQ=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/S3J1R-s_P481lUpBULskSiQ0Pv-Z_iLnE_YrZ10OL1cydCFx6a1aOXvRJskMxY-gVpa8cqwuzQ=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/S3J1R-s_P481lUpBULskSiQ0Pv-Z_iLnE_YrZ10OL1cydCFx6a1aOXvRJskMxY-gVpa8cqwuzQ=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "AndreoBee",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2021-08-12T06:59:40Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "dmhfSWj6r1CzXr4yopXkorSsVL0",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UCvXV0HSenVdIpdAuogNPuOQ"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2022-11-02T12:01:42Z",
        "channelId": "UCvXV0HSenVdIpdAuogNPuOQ",
        "title": "AndreoBee",
        "description": "PLZ  SUB.....",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/NfH1RxDcGEbLe8cOoi7VwFz-dfUcAToV-84rag4x1CIQM8GSnZirguR5SI30M3bZnMP80tA=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/NfH1RxDcGEbLe8cOoi7VwFz-dfUcAToV-84rag4x1CIQM8GSnZirguR5SI30M3bZnMP80tA=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/NfH1RxDcGEbLe8cOoi7VwFz-dfUcAToV-84rag4x1CIQM8GSnZirguR5SI30M3bZnMP80tA=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "AndreoBee",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2022-11-02T12:01:42Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "c5Y3zUOZKiyJ-pI7mrLdi4WPegc",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UCmrR9PVxSVRLdp2HK_xP2yA"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-09-13T06:16:47Z",
        "channelId": "UCmrR9PVxSVRLdp2HK_xP2yA",
        "title": "ANDREOBEE",
        "description": "AndreoBee fan Club For business inquiries ANDREOBEEofficial.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/CtsMEUKLJC5apm5bX7vEr_3g7nIJn-GfjLodWXLVLF-jFGfyXhFBTiLUvOU8l51e3kVPph5MUQ=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/CtsMEUKLJC5apm5bX7vEr_3g7nIJn-GfjLodWXLVLF-jFGfyXhFBTiLUvOU8l51e3kVPph5MUQ=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/CtsMEUKLJC5apm5bX7vEr_3g7nIJn-GfjLodWXLVLF-jFGfyXhFBTiLUvOU8l51e3kVPph5MUQ=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "ANDREOBEE",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2021-09-13T06:16:47Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "-lb0jmjUJcQsLJDGHH7KVs14-nU",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UCvqm9nqHYYehmq7FcorjS4Q"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-01-13T05:54:00Z",
        "channelId": "UCvqm9nqHYYehmq7FcorjS4Q",
        "title": "AndreoBEE",
        "description": "",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AL5GRJUIkodf8aTOx2ZcNoyycMHQqgqNvehuXN_iz9Ii=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AL5GRJUIkodf8aTOx2ZcNoyycMHQqgqNvehuXN_iz9Ii=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AL5GRJUIkodf8aTOx2ZcNoyycMHQqgqNvehuXN_iz9Ii=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "AndreoBEE",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2021-01-13T05:54:00Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

N.B: for this case, I will accept that the first result is the channel I'm looking for, however, notice here that you might get more than one channel that matches the channel name.

For detect which one of the results of the search matches with the channel you're looking for, you could then, make a request to the channel:list endpoint - by passing the `channel_id` of the search result - and see their `customUrl` value and/or check the channel that has more videos/subscribers/etc.

Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75325524/12511801) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

You can get a channel id using `/search` Youtube API. Instead using this :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=${channelUsername}&key=myapi
```

Try with this endpoint :

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=${channelUsername}&type=channel&key=myapi
```

Comment: It is not giving the correct Id.
Correct ID = UCjdjyjdcdmldCK5XuuWbn1A
it is giving = UCnmkfAgbsF2dPt4DL2ZqUrQ

Comment: Have you tried with other index? `response.data.items[1].id`

Comment: The problem is that it is not showing the channel I need it is showing all other channels

Comment: How about this [https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?handle=@AndreoBee](https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?handle=@AndreoBee)

Comment: ok this url worked. Tell me one thing does this url also contains limits like google apis

Comment: According to the [https://yt.lemnoslife.com/](https://yt.lemnoslife.com/), there are no limitations at this moment, but future that can happen