# Fetch ChannelId by username using Youtube V3 API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on a project that requires that I get the channelId of a User using their username with the Youtube V3 API and I'm facing some difficulty understanding what to set as the value of the "forUsername" param.

Looking at it, I believe that my misunderstanding comes from using the Account handle as the Username since while the request below

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=API_KEY&forUsername=ganba_roll&part=id

(Example for https://www.youtube.com/@ganba_roll)

doesn't return any results:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "RuuXzTIr0OoDqI4S0RU6n4FqKEM",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 0,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    }
}
```

A similar question's answer that used the request below as an example of how to retrieve a users channelId with the v3 API

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=API_KEY&forUsername=klauskkpm&part=id

successfully returns

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "_eCbyZfbnzEHno7A-oBcP0LCzlI",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    },
    "items": [
       {
          "kind": "youtube#channel",
          "etag": "JhuO0pv2b8motmYfYWvQrmif2a8",
          "id": "UCfjTOrCPnAblTngWAzpnlMA"
       }
    ]
}
```

I'm confused as to where to retrieve the value that I need to set the forUsername param to.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Deepening [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73807243) should help you.

Comment: Your service is incredible!

Comment: @soup se [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75374713/12511801) as well if you want an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if the question is still open, but i'll try it :)

The forUsername parameter is only relevant for channels that have the youtube.com/user/… url. These are old channels made before may 2009.