# About Youtube channels and YouTube API v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was wondering why is that that some channels return an array in the following code and other don't? I'm trying to make a video gallery but the specific channel won't return me that array that has contentDetails. I also have access to the youtube account if I need to change any settings in there to allow this code to work. I also already have api credentials and added API v3 to the project.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
            part: 'contentDetails',
            forUsername: channelName,
            key: 'myKeyvalue'},
            function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                //upload_id = data.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
            }
    )
}
```

Thanks in advance.

The data object should contain an array.

Comment: Maybe you're confused between all different YouTube channel identifiers, see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73807243) for more details. If you don't solve your problem with this answer, then please share an example of `channelName` returning an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behaviour might be due the `channelName` value is different from the *common/public* name.

*Example:*

> If you want to check the channel `Markiplier`, for search this channel
> using the `channels.list` endpoint, you have to use the value
> `markiplierGAME` as value in the `forUsername` field.

So, as alternative you have to get the correct value for the `forUsername` field or, use the `id` - in this case, the `channel_id`.