# I can't get channel id using YouTube Data API v3

Tags: http, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get the YouTube channel id by its username, but in the end I get nothing. The username and API key are correct. What could be the problem?

HTTP Request:
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=fugu1449&key=apikey`

Response:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "RuuXzTIr0OoDqI4S0RU6n4FqKEM",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 0,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75325601/12511801) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75769587/12511801) as well.

Answer (score 4):

### YouTube channel various ids

- All YouTube channels have ids and handles, such as respectively [`UC0aMPje3ZACnQPKM_qzY0vw`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0aMPje3ZACnQPKM_qzY0vw) and [`@redcross`](https://www.youtube.com/@redcross), these channels are accessible at respectively: https://www.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID and https://www.youtube.com/HANDLE
- Some YouTube channels may also have `c/` and `user/` ids such as respectively [`hugodecrypte`](https://www.youtube.com/c/hugodecrypte) and [`DonDiablo`](https://www.youtube.com/user/DonDiablo), these channels are accessible at respectively: https://www.youtube.com/c/C_ID and https://www.youtube.com/user/USER_ID

### YouTube Data API v3 partial support with these ids

YouTube Data API v3 mostly supports channel ids (the ones starting with `UC`) however it's possible with it to retrieve channel ids from channel `user/` ids thanks to [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) endpoint with [`forUsername`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#forUsername) filter.

However YouTube Data API v3 [doesn't provide the ability](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history) to retrieve channel ids from `c/` ids and handles.

### YouTube operational API completes this support

Nevertheless you can retrieve channel ids from `c/` ids and handles thanks to my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by fetching respectively https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?cId=C_ID and https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?handle=HANDLE you'll get the associated channel id.

For instance with [`hugodecrypte`](https://www.youtube.com/c/hugodecrypte) and [`@redcross`](https://www.youtube.com/@redcross) you would respectively obtain:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "UCAcAnMF0OrCtUep3Y4M-ZPw"
        }
    ]
}
```

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "UC0aMPje3ZACnQPKM_qzY0vw"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not like that:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=fugu1449&key=apikey
You need to specify `snippet` after `part`.
The supporting parameter for @Handle was added to Youtube data v3 on January 31, 2024. You can organize your query structure accordingly. It has to be like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forHandle=fugu1449&key=apiKey
```

or

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forHandle=@fugu1449&key=apiKey
```

and now you can use the [new parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history) `forHandle` ([docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#parameters))

> The forHandle parameter specifies a YouTube handle, thereby requesting the channel associated with that handle. The parameter value can be prepended with an @ symbol. For example, to retrieve the resource for the "Google for Developers" channel, set the forHandle parameter value to either GoogleDevelopers or @GoogleDevelopers. now you can use the [new parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history) `forHandle` ([docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#parameters))
> Example site: Channel ID Finder; https://ytlarge.com/youtube/channel-id-finder/
> this website gets the id of the channels, using forhandle.