# YouTube Data API gets channel info for some usernames but not for others

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get `snippet,contentDetails,statistics` part string by using YouTube Data API v3.

When I [fill in](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix=true) `forUsername` field with `GoogleDevelopers` it gets the details.

But when I fill in the usernames (custom_urls) for other channels say `InfinityLearnNEET`, it fetches 0 results.

I tried for the following urls:

```
https://www.youtube.com/@InfinityLearnNEET
https://www.youtube.com/@itsreallycrazy
https://www.youtube.com/@Mrcrazyvamshi
```

I wonder why?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807) solves your issue.