# Unable to retrieve channel resource for `/v3/channels` endpoint [YouTube API]

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am currently running into an issue where I am unable to retrieve a channel resource from the `/v3/channels` endpoint using the YouTube API (v3).

The expected behaviour is to get back a channel ID that I am then able to use with the `/v3/search` endpoint.

I am using Python and I am attempting to retrieve the resource by username with the `forUsername` query parameter.

My code looks like this:

```py
headers = { 
    "content-type": "application/json",
}

params = { 
    "part": "snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
    "forUsername": "<USERNAME_HERE>",
    "key": api_key
}

res = requests.get(channel_endpoint, headers=headers, params=params)
if res.status_code == 200:
    data = res.json()
    if data["pageInfo"]["totalResults"] == 0:
        print("no channel found")
    print(data["items"][0]["id"])

# Response:
# {'kind': 'youtube#channelListResponse', 'etag': 'RuuXzTIr0OoDqI4S0RU6n4FqKEM', 'pageInfo': {'totalResults': 0, 'resultsPerPage': 5}}
```

The odd thing is that I get back a response for certain channels but not all channels.

E.g. "GoogleDevelopers" will return a coherent and meaningful response. Although, my own channel or other external channels do not return a response.

I have already checked API key permissions, restrictions and anything aligned with using the API endpoint/s or keys themselves.

I have already tried to check the username accuracy, channel visibility settings and case sensitivity.

I've gone through multiple routes already and have even considered simply scraping the `channelId` from the page source.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing with [the various YouTube channel ids](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807)? If not, then please provide a `<USERNAME_HERE>` value.

Comment: Hi, I am sure I am sending the username. Here you go: @italymadeeasy (https://www.youtube.com/@italymadeeasy)

Comment: Please read carefully the link I sent you as it solves your issue.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison, I read carefully and have to say thank you for your work. I appreciate the help! Although, how do I distinguish between `cid`, `handle` and `username`?

Comment: Given `a_username` you can't determine offline if it's a `cId`, `handle` (where the `@` would have been removed) or `username`, you are obliged to check what YouTube UI returns for https://www.youtube.com/@a_username, https://www.youtube.com/c/a_username and https://www.youtube.com/user/a_username to guess what identifier type it is.