# Get the DateTime of all Videos from a YouTuber

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to do a fun project and calculate when a YouTuber is most likely to upload their next YouTube video based on previous releases and their release dates.

So I calculate how long the YouTuber needs on average between each upload, and then calculated when he will upload their next YouTube video.

But first I need all Date / Times from for example the last 50 videos of that specific YouTuber.
Currently I'm trying to do that with Python and the Google Cloud "YouTube Data API v3".

I found a few lines of code online:

```
import os
import googleapiclient.discovery
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

# Replace 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your API key or provide the path to your credentials file
api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

# Create the API client
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

def get_channel_subscriber_count(channel_id):
    try:
        response = youtube.channels().list(part='statistics', id=channel_id).execute()
        channel = response['items'][0]
        subscriber_count = channel['statistics']['subscriberCount']
        print(f"Subscriber Count: {subscriber_count}")
    except HttpError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# Replace 'CHANNEL_ID' with the ID of the specific YouTube channel
channel_id = 'CHANNEL_ID'
get_channel_subscriber_count(channel_id)
```

I replaced the API Key with mine, and changed the channel_id to the name of the YouTuber (youtube.com/@RemusNeo) so I replace it with "RemusNeo".
However I always get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Baseult\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 23, in
>
> get_channel_subscriber_count(channel_id)   File "C:\Users\Baseult\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 15, in
> get_channel_subscriber_count
> channel = response['items'][0] KeyError: 'items'

If I use the same code and do it manually with each video using the following code, then it works fine:

```
def get_video_details(video_id):
    try:
        response = youtube.videos().list(part='snippet', id=video_id).execute()
        video = response['items'][0]
        title = video['snippet']['title']
        release_date = video['snippet']['publishedAt']
        print(f"Title: {title}")
        print(f"Release Date: {release_date}")
    except HttpError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# Replace 'VIDEO_ID' with the ID of the specific YouTube video
video_id = 'VIDEO_ID'
get_video_details(video_id)
```

I tried a few other methods, for example get the Subscriber Count of that YouTuber but that also didn't work. So I guess the code is outdated to access a YouTubers channel?

Would be awesome if someone could help me, thanks a lot :)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807) will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the UserName because of the @Handle.
I had to use the channel ID instead which you can get here:
[I can't get channel id using YouTube Data API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75841604/i-cant-get-channel-id-using-youtube-data-api-v3/75843807#75843807)