# About ways to fetch information about a channel using YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube-api

I was analyzing the YouTube API and noticed something:

I want to fetch information about a channel. I saw that to query it using "[channel resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/channels?hl=en)" I need to have the channel ID. Is it not possible to make this query using just the URL of channel, right? I saw somewhere that it would work with the channel name, but then there could be multiple results due to channels having identical names. Wouldn't just having the channel URL be enough to directly query a channel?

Later, I discovered that I can retrieve the information by using the link of a video ([videos functions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos?hl=en)), where I can not only see the channel ID but also all other information about the channel.

So, can I fetch information about a channel using either the URL of one of its videos or its channel ID? Are those the only options?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807) solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I just didn't understand this API limitation of Google. Wouldn't it be better to allow searching by the channel url, instead of just the ID? Or if the ID was something easier to get, just as it used to appear in the url itself