# Is there any way to get youtube channel ID from youtube channel handles?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get channel ids of youtube channels I watch. I am able to get channel ids for youtube channels which have username using youtube data api. I am not able to do the same using channel handles. The username feature is old and very few channels display their username. Most channels only show their handles now.

Is there any method available in Youtube Data API which can get channel id from channel handles?

There is a method [to extract channel id from page source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oDy2sWPF38). But that involves scraping the youtube channel homepage.

There is also a way to use the youtube search API. But if I try a lesser known channel or a channel which has is a very common name in the search bar, I don't get the exact channel ID in the search results.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807) makes all that clear.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried getting channel ids using usernames using the link you provided. It works. Is it possible to get the latest activities of a channel using your operational API?

Comment: Your comment seems to be quite off-topic for Stack Overflow (as it's a question about something else than the initial question and making such a different Stack Overflow question specific to my API doesn't seem appropriate, what would fit on Stack Overflow is the question *is it possible to get the latest activities of a channel?*), joining [the YouTube operational API community](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/8e4c02201c00933702c21130321a2bce20836ed1/README.md#contact) seems to more appropriate. Anyway what do you define as *the latest activities of a channel*?