# Retrieving the channel list and video wise data as well their analytics

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

How can I list all the channels connected to my account using YouTube Data API or YouTube Analytics API?
Further how can I list all the videos of a specified channel along with its metrics to analyze the data using Analytics API

When I call the API with 'id = MINE', it returned only one channel. I tried using 'forUsername' filter to access each channels by their user name, but that method is returning no result.

With the main channel I can only get analytics summary of the channel, could not get the breakdown video wise, how can I breakdown it into the video level?

Comment: *along with its metrics* what metrics are you interested in?
[`forUsername`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#forUsername) can be misleading, are you sure you are keen on [the various YouTube channel id types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807)?
Concerning *breakdown video wise*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030).