# Search List returned multiple channels

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-java-client

I trying to send this request to get the channel

```
request = youtube.search().list("snippet");
request.setMaxResults(50);
request.setQ(channelName);
request.setType("channel");
```

we get multiple channels, not the same channel name
please can you help me why we get all these channels and how we resolve them?

Comment: What `channelName` are you trying with? Does not [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807) solves your issue?

Comment: for example if i setQ("@redcross") I will get to many channels on the same this name redcross did we have any solution filter to get only channels related to this name??

Comment: See [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77792620/search-list-returned-multiple-channels#comment137142980_77792620) as you are mentioning handles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [video.search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method q paramater does not search on channel name

it only searches on title and description.

[image]