# Extract YouTube channel name from the URL of the channel

Tags: google-sheets, youtube, google-sheets-formula, youtube-data-api

I have been trying to extract the name of YouTube channel from the URL in a google sheet. The data consists of 25K links and it is nearly impossible to open each link and then copy paste the name.

Adding the link to the first channel and sheet for reference as per the feedback: [www.youtube.com/channel/UCKaCalz5N5ienIbfPzEbYuA](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKaCalz5N5ienIbfPzEbYuA)

Please make a copy of this sheet to test the solutions. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lN8Xs_TVvnemW4W8rGVsUl-FyLQ-NIy9C0uC69lQt4I/edit?usp=sharing

E.g.

[image]

Any support here would be super helpful.

Thanks!

I have tried using the formula from other posts on stackoverflow but all of them are returning "N/A"

Comment: The channel name is what is in the column/URL, or you need to load the link to get the name? E.g. is `UCK...` what you want?

Comment: please edit the post with the link to the channel.

Comment: Use [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint with [`part`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part)`=`[`snippet`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet), as you are interested in [`snippet/title`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.title). Concerning URLs resolution, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807) should help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`IMPORTDATA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335) function:

```cpp
=LET(data,TOCOL(IMPORTDATA(A1)),
     FILTER(
       REGEXEXTRACT(data,"name: ""(.*?)"""),
       REGEXMATCH(data,"name: """)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it is giving "N/A" for any link I am using this formula for. Is there anything I am missing here? I have added the link to the google sheet in the original post so that you can cross check?

Comment: Tried with "https://" and it worked!! THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=importxml(A2,"//meta[@property='og:title']/@content")
```

[image]

***DISCLAIMER***: *`import` functions can go into overload mode (exceed the limit) if you are trying to pull data from thousands of URLs in a go & most likely will result in loading forever*

Comment: Thanks for the above. Unfortunately, this is also giving "#NA" for all the channels. Can you please check if I am missing anything here? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lN8Xs_TVvnemW4W8rGVsUl-FyLQ-NIy9C0uC69lQt4I/edit?hl=en_GB&pli=1#gid=0

Comment: missing `https://` part in your test sheet URLs; go with `=importxml("https://"&A2,"//meta[@property='og:title']/@content")`