# Why is the YouTube Data API v3 not returning 'items' in channelListResponse for a specific username?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the YouTube Data API v3 to fetch details about a specific YouTube channel using the forUsername parameter. However, my request is returning a response without the expected items field. Below is the curl command I'm using:

```bash
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?forUsername=irodorimidori&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

return

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "RuuXzTIr0OoDqI4S0RU6n4FqKEM",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  }
}
```

why it dont return

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "prevPageToken": string,
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": integer,
    "resultsPerPage": integer
  },
  "items": [
    channel Resource
  ]
}
```

i dont find items in return

Comment: It seems that you are confuzing channel handles and usernames, as you believe that [@irodorimidori](https://www.youtube.com/@irodorimidori) is a username while it is a handle, see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807).