# How to get YOU TUBE channel's id by its public link?

Tags: python, youtube, google-api-client, pytube

How to get personal id of YT channel by his public link with "@"(for example:youtube.com/@pewdiepie)? I need it for correctly work of pytube(class Channel()). I'm inclined to use googleapiclient, but I will be happy with any solution.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807) may help you.